# How can I display all fields from a Many-to-Many Model in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, many-to-many, displayobject

I have the following Models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    some_field_A = models.CharField()
    some_other_field_A = models.CharField()
    
class ModelB(models.Model):
    some_field_B = models.CharField()
    many_to_many_relation = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA)
```

In `admin.py` I am using filter_horizontal to edit the ManyToManyField:

```
class ModelB(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = ModelB
    filter_horizontal = ('many_to_many_relation',)
```

but it shows only `some_field_A` and I want it to show both fields from ModelA, because the entries in ModelA are unique depending on both fields and as you can see from the picture there are multiple entries with the same value (i.e. `some_field_A = EUV`) but they have different values for `some_other_field_A`:

[image]

Comment: It makes use of the `__str__` method you defined in `ModelA`.

Comment: Thank you so much! can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It displays the result of the `__str__(…)` method you defined in your `ModelA`, so if you return the value of `some_field` in the `__str__(…)` method, then it will return only the data of `some_field`.

You thus can alter this method and return both fields:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    some_field_A = models.CharField()
    some_other_field_A = models.CharField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.some_field_A} {self.some_other_field_A}'
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this exactly the solution you are looking for but you could override the `__str__` method of `ModelA` to return the information in a single line.

So for example:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
  first_field = models.CharField(max_length=16)
  second_field = models.CharField(max_length=16)

  def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.first_field} ({self.second_field'})"
```

Your admin view should then show each object as "foo (bar)"